# Installation of tensorflow_data_validation in Jupyter Notebook runs indefinitely

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-data-validation

I am trying to install tensorflow_data_validation via the command pip install tensorflow_data_validation in my local Jupyter notebook environment, but the installation gets stuck and never completes. Even after 20-25 minutes or more, it does not successfully install tensorflow_data_validation.

Are there any troubleshooting steps you would recommend to resolve this installation hang up, or any other way to install tensorflow_data_validation? I also tried downloading tensorflow_data_validation from Github, but then I keep getting errors saying some dependency is missing, and if I install one dependency it will say some other dependency is missing. This is the current missing dependency according to the error message:

[Error text on installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB924.png)

```
]: import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv |

Error importing tfx_bsl_extension.arrow.array_util. Some tfx_bsl functionalities are not availableError importing tfx_bsl_exten sion.arrow.table_util. Some tfx_bsl functionalities are not available: No module named 'tfx_bsl.cc.tfx_bsl_extension 'Error impo rting tfx_bsl_extension.statistics. Some tfx_bsl functionalities are not available: No module named 'tfx_bsl.cc.tfx_bsl_extensi on'Error importing tfx_bsl_google_extension.arrow.sql_util. Some tfx_bsl functionalities are not available: No module named 'tf x_bsl.cc.tfx_bsl_extension'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv

File ~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_data_validation\___init__.py:18, in <module> 
     15 """Init module for TensorFlow Data Validation."""
     17 # Import stats API.
---> 18 from tensorflow_data_validation.api.stats_api import default_sharded_output_suffix 
     19 from tensorflow_data_validation.api.stats_api import default_sharded_output_supported 
     20 from tensorflow_data_validation.api.stats_api import GenerateStatistics

File \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_data_validation\api\stats_api.py:52, in <module> 
     50 import pyarrow as pa
     51 from tensorflow_data_validation.utils import artifacts_io_impl
---> 52 from tensorflow_data_validation.statistics import stats_impl
     53 from tensorflow_data_validation. statistics import stats_options
     54 from tfx_bs1.statistics import merge_util

File ~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_data_validation\statistics\stats_impl.py:27, in <module> 
     25 from tensorflow_data_validation.arrow import arrow_util
     26 from tensorflow_data_validation.utils import preprocessing_util
---> 27 from tensorflow_data_validation.statistics import stats_options
     28 from tensorflow_data_validation.statistics.generators import basic_stats_generator
     29 from tensorflow_data_validation.statistics.generators import image_stats_generator

File \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_data_validation\statistics\stats_options.py:31, in <module> 
     29 from tensorflow_data_validation.utils import example_weight_map
     30 from tensorflow_data_validation.utils import schema_util
---> 31 from tensorflow_data_validation.utils import slicing_util
     32 from tfx_bs1.arrow import sql_util
     33 from tfx_bs1.coders import example_coder

File \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_data_validation\utils\slicing_util.py:41, in <module> 
     39 from tfx_bs1.arrow import sql_util
     40 from tfx_bsl.arrow import table_util
---> 41 from tfx_bsl.public.proto import slicing_spec_pb2
     42 from tensorflow_metadata.proto.ve import statistics_pb2
     45 _ValueType = Iterable [Union [Text, int, bytes]]

ImportError: cannot import name 'slicing_spec_pb2' from 'tfx_bsl.public.proto' (C:\Users\<path>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tfx_
bsl\public\proto\___init__.py)
```

Comment: Provide the console dump for the installation in text formatted as code not a screen shot?